# Replace multiple occurrences of same string in href using Regular Expressions

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex, replace

Our CMS is (I suppose correctly) encoding comma characters in URLs. So instead of being "?values=1,2,3" the CMS is rendering "?values=1%2c2%2c3". This in itself is not a problem however the external system that these links are pointing at cannot handle the encoded commas and only works if we pass actual commas in the query string.

We already have a Regex clean-up tool that processes the HTML pre-render and cleans out non XHTML compliant mark-up. This is an old CMS running on ASP.Net v2.

My question is what regular expression would be required to swap out all occurrences of "%2c" for a comma, but only where this text exists within an anchor tag. I've been easily able to swap out all instances of %2c but this runs the risk of corrupting the page elsewhere if that string happened to be used for a non-URL purpose.

I'm using .Net and System.Text.RegularExpressions. We have an XML file that contains all of the Find and Replace rules. This gets loaded at runtime and cleans the HTML. Each rule consists of:

- Text to find -    e.g. `"<script>`"
- Text to replace - e.g. `"<script type='text/javascript'>"`

We then have some C# that loops over each of the rules and does the following:

```
// HTML = full page HTML
Regex regex = new Regex(searchTxt, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
HTML = regex.Replace(HTML, replaceTxt);
```

Simple as that. I just can't get the right regex syntax for our specific scenario.

Many thanks for your help.

## Here is a complete C# console app that hopefully explains my scenario

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string html = GetPageHTML();
        string regexString = "(<a href=).*|(%2c)";
        string replaceTxt = ",";

        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline;
        Regex regex = new Regex(regexString, options);

        // We are currently using a simple regex.Replace
        string cleanHTML = regex.Replace(html, replaceTxt);

        // But for this example should we be doing something with the Matches collection?
        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(html))
        {
            if (match.Success)
            {
                // do something?
            }
        }

    }

    private static string GetPageHTML()
    {
        return @"<html>
                    <head></head>
                    <body>
                        <a title='' href='http://www.testsite.com/?x=491191%2cy=291740%2czoom=6%2cbase=demo%2clayers=%2csearch=text:WE9%203QA%2cfade=false%2cmX=0%2cmY=0' target='_blank'>A link</a>
                        <p>We wouldn't want this (%2c) to be replaced</p>
                    </body>
                </html>";
    }
}
```

Comment: HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode tried that?

Comment: No. I don't have an instance of the string in memory where I can do that. I just have the whole HTML page where I can effectively do a find and replace using regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

If .net would support pcre regex you could do something like this:

```
^(?!<a href=").*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(%2c)
```

That is what you want. Above regex will match only `%2c` inside anchor tags. But you could achieve the same if you use regex the regex discard technique plus some logic.

If you use below regex, you could match `%2c` and also capture the `%2c` string that is within anchor tags:

```
^(?!<a href=").*|(%2c)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/jH7yR8/1)**

[image]

So, what you can do is to add logic and to check if the capturing group content is equal to `%2c`, in that case means that it matches `%2c` from the anchor tag. Then you can replace that for a comma.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand it fully though so I'm not sure if you are right or not. I can see in your demo that the pattern also matches outside of the <a> which is not what I'm after, but I suspect you've explained a way around this, I'm just not quite following you. I've updated my question with a bit more detail. With this added context are you able to expand on your answer?

Comment: @j.strugnell in my answer what I explain is to use a regex technique. In the screenshot you can see in green the matches you care and in blue what you don't care. So, you use this regex to capture the string you want using capturing group. The logic you would need to use is: `if (captureGroup is not empty) then replace the string`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'll have a look at this further tomorrow and let you know if I crack it. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry I can't get this to work. I'm going to edit the question to include some sample C# console code to help people replicate my scenario.

Comment: For this we decided to replace all instances of %2c in the page as I could not get it to target just anchor tags. Thank you for your help @Fede, I can't tick your answer as "the" answer as I could not get it to work. But that is most likely due to my own lack of Regex skills... ;0) Thanks.